# Getting Error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have simple `DataTable`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
[Id]   INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

With one record, `Name="Test"` `Id` get's automatic 0.

When I am using basic create operation

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Table table)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Table.Add(table);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(table);
}
```

I get error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What I am doing wrong? How to fix this error?

Table class

```
public partial class Table
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you are using data base first approach why are you generating models manually and not using entity data model to generate it automatically(as it is done here: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`IsDbGenerated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdbgenerated(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`. Add `System.Data.Linq` to your references then:

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Storage = "Id", DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It smells like the table that you are retrieving from the argument (`Table table`) is setting the property `Id` to other value than `0`.

If that's the case, be sure that you set the `Id` to `0` before `db.Table.Add(table);`

If you want to update the item if it exists, then you need to check if the `Id` is  `0` before adding it.

```
if(table.Id == 0)
   db.Table.Add(table);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

This worked for me.